# Javascript and json pharse loop with external file

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops, while-loop

I should loop this json file to javascript, all the entries are important and must be retrieved.
I need to make this json compatible with this javascript code.

**This is my json file:**

```
{ "user_token":"6664e310e87f75ad4fd5674a976f8310", "lesson_language":"it_de", "language_app":"it", "main_levels":[ { "level":"1_it_de" }, { "level":"5_it_de" } ] }
```

**This is my code javascript:**

```
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "myTutorials.txt";

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            myFunction(myArr);
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();

    function myFunction(arr) {
        var out = "";
        var i;
        var user_token = arr[0].user_token;
        for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var level = arr[i].level;
            out += user_token;
        }
        document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
    }
```

Comment: You've mixed arrays and objects, in the file you seem to have an object, and `user_token` is a property of that object.

Comment: What should be the output ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var jsonInput={ "user_token":"6664e310e87f75ad4fd5674a976f8310", "lesson_language":"it_de", "language_app":"it", "main_levels":[ { "level":"1_it_de" }, { "level":"5_it_de" } ] }

function myFunction(arr) {
        var out = "";
        var i;
        var userLabel=''
        var user_token = arr.user_token;
        mainArrObj=arr.main_levels
        for(i = 0; i < mainArrObj.length; i++) {
        var level = mainArrObj[i].level;
            out += user_token + '  ';
            userLabel += level + '  ';
        }
        console.log('user_token :'+out);
        console.log('userLabel :'+userLabel);
}

myFunction(jsonInput)
```